# How to send textfield value using ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i'm trying to display mysql table value when page onload ().i've used ajax function to call php mysql page.what i want to do is,i want to pass textfield value from ajax.but it dn't show any result.this is what i have tried.

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id;?>" id="rid" />

<script>
function showAll() {

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("bookings").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  var resname= document.getElementById("rid").value();

  xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_all.php?res_name="+resname,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

in ajax_all.php

```
echo $id = $_REQUEST['res_name'];
```

Comment: what r u getting in response??

Comment: no any result.it's display blank page.

Comment: try doing var_dump($id); die; not echo

Comment: @Ceeee same result.blank page. :(

Answer (score 0):

Please do like this, i hope it will help to get response

```
    if($_GET['id'])
    {
       $id=$_GET['id'];}
     else {
     $id = 'null';
     }

     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id;?>" id="rid" />
     <button type="button" onclick="showAll()">Change Content</button>
    <script>
    function showAll() {

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("rid").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      var resname= document.getElementById("rid").value();

      xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_all.php?res_name="+resname,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: same result.blank page.i think function didn't identified textfield value.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this one help you.

```
<input type="hidden" value="123" id="rid" />
```

Your script function.

```
 function showAll()
    {
        var  resname = $('#rid').val();
        var data_string = "res_name=" + resname;
        $.ajax({

            url: 'ajax_all.php',
            data: data_string,
            type: post
            success:  function(html){

                  $("#bookings").innerHTML= html
            }


        });
    }
```

Hope you have already attached `jquery.min.js`.

[For Demo click here.](https://jsfiddle.net/viranijigs/uhdw97hu/2/)

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me

booking.php

```
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id;?>" name="rid" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        function showAll() {

        var resname = $("input[name='rid']").val();


            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax_all.php',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {res_name:resname},
                success: function(data) {
                   document.getElementById('bookings').innerHTML =data;
                }
            });

        }
        </script>
 <body onload="showAll()" >   
    <div id="bookings"></div>
</body>
```

in ajax_all.php

```
$id = $_REQUEST['res_name'];
```

thanks all.specially @jigs Virani